# Performance gain from custom state container to Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, mobx, sails.io.js, mobx-react

We have a sails-js app whose ui is built with React and state container custom created with MVVM method. Our app takes ridiculously too much memory (over 400mb) even when user isn't doing anything. At times it also just crashes (on the iphone cordova build specifically). Also, even though we do not have much actions involved (except loading and playing some web audio songs etc), our webpack bundle is over 18mb (unminimised, 2,5mb minimised).

So what could be the reason for the lagging performance and the oversized bundle? How can I fix it? One option I'm thinking that will hopefully resolve the matter is to implement Mobx instead of our custom solution for state management. Because it is extremely complicated for me and there's absolutely no documentation for it. Would you have reasons that will likely resolve my problem as well?

Thanks!

Comment: took a quick look at your dist/main.js, it has lots of stuff like jQuery, sizzle?... start your optimization from here. You can split the code, remove unnecessary stuff.

Comment: IMO, i dont think you can gain a lot of performance improvement by switching to Mobx unless your custom state management solution is way to large in size.

Comment: But the problem is that I do not know the dynamics of the custom state solution that was written and it will probably take me much more time trying to optimise it than making an entirely new solution that adopts a well-documented, largely contributed resource tool like mobx. It's also a sort of future safe solution I feel, especially that I'd like to leave something whose methodology is documented. Like you say we also overuse a lot of libraries like underscore and jquery, which I'd resist to use at all if I do something from scratch.